# Can imports be bound in a 64 bit executable?

Tags: linker, portable-executable, aslr

I've tried to bind a 64bit executable (I'm using Win7 x64) using bind.exe which seemed perfectly happy to bind the 64 bit exe and its output using the verbose option seemed reasonable.  In spite of that, it resulted in an executable that crashes during initialization - various pointers pointed to the "wrong" place and "no place".

Just in case, I tried binding the imports using CFF Explorer but, the result and the problem(s) were the same.

**My question or better stated, my request is:** does someone have an authoritative answer as to whether or not a 64 bit executable can or cannot have its imports bound and the reason(s) why ?  If the answer is affirmative, the question is how ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  The imports of a 64bit executable can be bound.  There are a number of dlls in Windows 7 64bit that are bound.

However, the bind.exe distributed with MS VS2017 does not bind 64bit executables correctly (at least not at the time of this writing.)

I have not come across a way to correctly bind 64bit executables. Therefore, the "how" stays unanswered.